flutter GoRouter : close ModalBottomsheet on back pressed
I have an app that use goRoute with bottomNavigation bar, and inside any routes i need to open a ModalBottomSheet (over bottomNavBar) for show some data.
Here it is an example of my goRouter implementation:
static final router = GoRouter(
initialLocation: homePath,
navigatorKey: rootNavKey,
routes: [
  StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
    builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
      return MainScreen(
        navigationShell: navigationShell,
      );
    },
    branches: [
      // home branch
      StatefulShellBranch(navigatorKey: homeNavKey, routes: homeRoutes),
      StatefulShellBranch(navigatorKey: otherNavKey, routes: Routes),
    ],
  ),
],);


static final otherRoutes = [
GoRoute(
  path: otherMainPath,
  pageBuilder: (context, state) {
    return OtherPage();
  },
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
        path: otherDetailPath,
        pageBuilder: (context, state) {
         return OtherDetailPage();
        }),
  ],
)];

Now, if i open a modalBottomSheet from inside OtherDetailPage, if i press device back button modalBottomSheet does not close, but app navigates back to OtherPage
This is how i open modalBottomSheet:
 showModalBottomSheet(
  isScrollControlled: true,
  useRootNavigator: true,
  context: context,
  enableDrag: false,
  builder: (context) {
    return MyModalContent();
  },
);

I want that modal closes on back button. How can i fix it?

Same problem. Tried PopScope and override backButtonDispatcher. It doesn't help.

This problem has an issue on github

Simple solution its downgrade to v12
Try workaround with code


